# WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils (file:/C:/Users/.../spring-core/5.3.14/spring-core-5.3.14.jar)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

При настройке spring-integration-sftp появилось сообщение:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils (file:/C:/Users/.../.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.3.14/spring-core-5.3.14.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Хотелось бы избавится от этого предупреждения. Если я допустил ошибку в коде вызывающее данное сообщение то укажите пожалуйста это место. Код моего файла конфигурации:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.expression.common.LiteralExpression;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Gateway;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;

import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.gateway.SftpOutboundGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory;

import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpRemoteFileTemplate;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.LsEntry;

import java.io.File;

@Configuration
public class SftpConfig {

    @Value("${sftp.hostName}")
    private String hostName;
    @Value("${sftp.hostPort}")
    private int hostPort;
    @Value("${sftp.hostUser}")
    private String hostUser;
    @Value("${sftp.hostPass}")
    private String hostPass;
    @Value("${sftp.remoteDirectory}")
    private String hostRemoteDirectory;

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;
    

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost(hostName);
        factory.setPort(hostPort);
        factory.setUser(hostUser);
        factory.setPassword(hostPass);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(factory);
    }


    @MessagingGateway
    public interface MyGateway {
        @Gateway(requestChannel = "sftpChannel")
        String putFile(File source);
    }


    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler1(){
        SftpRemoteFileTemplate sftpRemoteFileTemplate = new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(sftpSessionFactory());
        sftpRemoteFileTemplate.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(hostRemoteDirectory));
        SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpRemoteFileTemplate,"put","payload");
        sftpOutboundGateway.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
        return sftpOutboundGateway;
    }

}
```

Меня смущает то что если закомментировать:

```
    @MessagingGateway
    public interface MyGateway {
        @Gateway(requestChannel = "sftpChannel")
        String putFile(File source);
    }
```

То предупреждения пропадают.
Мой pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoSpringBatch</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demoSpringBatch</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency><!-- version 5.5.7 -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-sftp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.18</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.17</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/swagger/api.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <language>java</language>
                            <library>resttemplate</library>
                            <configOptions>
                                <dateLibrary>java11</dateLibrary>
                            </configOptions>
                            <output>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources</output>
                            <modelPackage>com.example.demoSpringBatch.model</modelPackage>
                            <generateApis>false</generateApis>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <ignoreFileOverride>${project.basedir}/.swagger-codegen-ignore</ignoreFileOverride>
                        </configuration>

                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: перевод слова «warining» на русский язык — не «ошибка», а «предупреждение».

Comment: Подправил вопрос. Я видел ответы вроде https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22674 но я столкнулся с возникновением после того как стал настраивать  spring-integration-sftp. Если вам что нибудь известно по данному вопросу то дайте знать. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: это стандартные библиотеки спринга использующие рефлексию, естественно при использовании рефлексии вы будете получать предупреждения

Comment: Почему предупреждение звучит как Illegal reflective access? Или все же я не правильно написал код? Может в конфигурацию нужно что нибудь добавить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если код работает как запланировано и как рекомендуется, значит с ним все нормально. Предупреждение исходит из spring-core `org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils`, который используется везде и рядом в библиоетеках Spring. Рефлексия это та жертва, которую приходиться нести, когда мы хотим получить удовольствие от POJO-конфигурации. Но так как Spring ничего не знает о наших объектах и их методах на этапе его компиляции приходится полагаться на рефлексию.

`@MessagingGateway` один из таких случаев: мы предоставляем только интерфейс, а всё остльное за нас делает библиотека. Доступ к нашим методам и их проксирование происходит через рефлексию.

Я думаю Вы не видете больше такого предупреждения, т.к. Ваша конфигурация довольно короткая.

На данный момент приходиться просто игнорировать такое предупреждение. Можно настроит logger для `org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils` категории на ERROR.

Comment: *"мы хотим получить удовольствие от POJO-конфигурации"* - месье знает толк